# The Looping through a Static Resource List is Not Obeying Conditions

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, static-resources, loop

In a test, I load a static resource containing 17 records (rows)  for my custom *Case Assignment* object.

A checkbox on this object is named Incorrect__c.

Three of the records have Incorrect__c of FALSE while the rest are TRUE:

```
List<sObject> caseAssignments = 
Test.loadData(Case_Assignment__c.sObjectType, 'Case_Assignments');
```

When I run the test containing the load above, the code below acquires the following coverage:

[image]

I can't figure out why `correctAssignments++` doesn't execute, since there are definitely rows in the static resource that meet the **else** condition.

On further inspection via the debug log below, *all* the records in the static resource are in fact being read as having Incorrect__c equal to TRUE.

[image]

But like I said at the beginning of this question, the data in the static resource is as below:

[image]

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is always true because it is an *assignment* whose resulting value is true:

```
if(ca.Incorrect__c = true){
```

This:

```
if(ca.Incorrect__c){
```

or this:

```
if(ca.Incorrect__c == true){
```

should work.

Comment: This question (and thus answer) is the reason why I recommend never comparing a Boolean to true or false, but instead using it as a Boolean.